# Use VBA to direct cell contents from Excel into PowerPoint presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-2019

I am using VBA code in Excel to create a slide in PowerPoint for each row of the spreadsheet. The following code works correctly in opening a new presentation and creating a new slide for each row as highlighted in my spreadsheet. It places the 1st cell of the row within the Title placeholder  of the new slide:

```
Sub LoopRowsSelected()

Dim DataRange As Range
Dim DataRow As Range
Dim DataColumn As Range


Dim AppPPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim Prs As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim Sld As PowerPoint.Slide

Set AppPPT = New PowerPoint.Application
Set Pres = AppPPT.Presentations.Open("C:\Test\Sample.potx")

AppPPT.Visible = True

Set DataRange = Selection

For Each DataRow In DataRange.Rows
    
    Set Sld = Pres.Slides.AddSlide(Pres.Slides.Count + 1, Pres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts(1))
 
        Sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 1)

    Next DataRow

End Sub
```

I had thought by naming each placeholder within the template differently, and then by copying this line:

```
Sld.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 1)
```

And adding it to look like this:

```
Sld.Shapes.Description.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 2)
```

It would insert the second cell of the row into the placeholder named "Description". It comes back with an error stating "Compile error: Method or data member not found". Obviously, I'm barking up the wrong tree in thinking "Title" is the actual "Title" selection object name in the template.

My question is, **what do I need to do differently to direct the cell contents to the correct placeholder in the PPT template?** Mind you (as you've already figured out), I'm not a programming, VBA, or Excel expert. I do not have a very good understanding of methods and hierarchy of elements, which I'm sure is causing me issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
 Sld.Shapes("Description").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = DataRow.Cells(1, 2)
```

When you name the placeholders in the Master Slide, the names do not automatically transfer over to a created slide. You'll have to know what those placeholder names are in order to code it correctly in the VBA. If a regular text frame, the first of them will most likely be "TextBox #" where the "#" symbol would be the incremented number as more objects get put into the master slide. You can figure out what the names are by going to the ribbon and selecting **Format** -> **Selection Pane**, then selecting the object you want to know the name of in order to highlight it in the selection pane.